# Sending an audio file WCF to WP7

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, windows-phone-7, audio

HI,

I want to send an audio file from WCF service to Windows Phone 7 application.

I wanted to know what audio format is best handled in this case and also some links that could help me make the application play that audio file.

The audio file would be downloaded via GPRS/3G

Thanks

Comment: What kind of audiofile? Music or speech? And is it really a file, or do you want some kind of stream?

Comment: it is a speech. I want to translate text to speech on the server and return the speech

Comment: For that use you have a wide choice of codecs. I'd look into Vorbis, Speex(I think there are pure C# implementations for both available) or WMA which I think has built in support.

Comment: do you know of any good link explaining WMA support?

Comment: No, I used Vorbis in my project because it's patent free and it's non GPLed open source. I suspect Mono has limited wma support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering instead of commenting so this can be voted on. Choosing a codec that is not on this list ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087(v=VS.92).aspx)  will be problematic for you. To my knowledge there is no way to play an audio file outside of using one of these formats (I could be wrong). Regardless (for a WP7 app) I would stick with on of the standard codecs.

You have a couple options.. you can use the standard Silverlight MediaElement (which will let you play any of the aforementioned codecs) or you can leverage the XNA library's SoundEffect/SoundEffectInstance classes (A good starting place for SoundEffect is here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.aspx). The XNA classes will give you more flexibility, BUT (from what I have read) you will be limited to WAV files only (someone can corect me if I'm wrong).

Comment: The initial comment about being voted on is more about the fact that I wanted to vote down the comments you were getting... I'm about 90% sure that you can only use a codec from the provided list.. so the advice was bad IMO.. (I realize just now that I could have flagged it, but it's not offensive.. just not good advice)

Comment: +1. Great info here, though it's worrisome that I've heard bad things about MediaElement (can't play many mp3s simultaneously?) and that SoundEffect doesn't support any form of compressed audio. This will make app sizes go up along with download times.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just created a music player that did that very thing. I recommend using a stream and using MediaElement to play the stream. Or, you can do as I did and turn the sound file to a URL. Then, use the XNA MediaPlayer to play the URL. It is very capable and even buffers the song enough to play without waiting for the whole file to download.